# i need help in storing multiple user input into an array with maximum limitation and being able to call it later in the code

Tags: java

Im still learning java and i want to understand more about array. Im still in school and we were asked to create an asean phonebook which can store, edit, delete, and view/search the information that are inputted. Im still doing the storing of information block of code and im struggling how to save multiple input in an array that is limited only to 100 contacts and can be searched later in the code. Can someone help me with my task and make me understand??

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Phonebook
{

```
public static void main (String [] args)
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    int i = 0;
    String studentNumber, surName, firstName, occuPation, countryCode, areaCode, numBer;
    char genDer;

    

    do
    {
    Menu();
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.print("Go to: ");
    String choice = input.next();
        if (choice.equals("1") || choice.equals("2") || choice.equals("3") || choice.equals("4") || choice.equals("5"))
        {
            i++;
            switch(choice)
            {
                
                
            case "1":System.out.println("Enter student number: ");
                     studentNumber = input.next();
                     System.out.println("Enter surname: ");
                     surName = input.next();
                     System.out.println("Enter first name: ");
                     firstName = input.next();
                     System.out.println("Enter occupation: ");
                     occuPation = input.next();
                     System.out.println("Enter gender (M for male, F for female): ");
                     genDer = input.next(); 
                     System.out.println("Enter counter code: ");
                     countryCode = input.next();
                     System.out.println("Enter area code: ");
                     areaCode = input.next();
                     System.out.println("Enter number: ");
                     numBer = input.next();
                     
            break;
        
            case "2":System.out.println("2");break;
            case "3":System.out.println("3");break;
            case "4":System.out.println("4");break;
            case "5":System.out.println("5");break;
            
            }
        }
        else 
        {
        System.out.println("Invalid keyword, Please try again");
        }
    }
    while (i < 1);
    
    
    
}

static void Menu()
{
    System.out.println("[1] Store to ASEAN phonebook");
    System.out.println("[2] Edit entry in ASEAN phonebook");
    System.out.println("[3] Delete entry from ASEAN phonebook");
    System.out.println("[4] View\\search ASEAN phonebook");
    System.out.println("[5] Exit");
}
```

}

Comment: you will probably need a class (you could name it ````Contact````) to hold the contact information for 1 person. You can then create an array of contacts like this: ````Contact[] contactArray = new Contact[100];```` When the user decides to store a contact you will need to create a ````new Contact()````, set the information and store it in the array.